# Status bar is hidden is some cases

Tags: objective-c, ios, media-player, statusbar

I have a problem with status bar. I'm working with MediaPlayer. When I watch a video and press a button "Done" there is status bar. But when I watch video, press button "Pause" and then press button "Done" there is NO status bar. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `hidden` property after you press the **Done** button?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: NO];
```

Comment: yes, I have this property in -(void)moviePlayDidFinish:(NSNotification*)aNotification

Comment: try moving it to `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: this method doesn't call when I press the Done button.

Comment: what "view" appears when you dismiss the media player?

Comment: I think problem with bounds or frame my view